# How do I use imagejpeg() with $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]

Tags: python, php, tensorflow2.0

My TensorFlow project only accepts JPEG because that is what I trained it on. I use a PHP image upload form to post the image. Here is how the image is received by the PHP file and is then used in my Python script.

```
 $uploaded_file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/tmp/classify-img");

 $output = shell_exec("/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/html/classify.py /tmp/classify-img");
```

I have used `imagejpeg()` in the past to convert any picture file extension to .jpeg

When I try this it just won't work though.

```
$uploaded_file = imagejpeg($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/tmp/classify-img");
```

Good job helping me. Thank you.

**Updated & Working Code**

```
#move the uploaded file somewhere temporary
$uploaded_file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/tmp/classify-img");

#Is WEBP image?
if (exif_imagetype("/tmp/classify-img".$_FILES["tmp_name"]) == IMAGETYPE_WEBP) {

    //create from webp temp image to be converted
    $im = imagecreatefromwebp("/tmp/classify-img".$_FILES["tmp_name"]);

    // Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

    // Output the image
    imagejpeg($im, "/tmp/classify-img".$_FILES["tmp_name"], 100);
}

$output = shell_exec("/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/html/classify.py /tmp/classify-img");
```

The problem was as mentioned below in the comments when you use `$_FILES["tmp_name"]` it gives you the file temporary file name when you use `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` you get the `tmp/` part added to your files path.

Thank you for the help everyone. Future readers I hope this helps explain how temporary files work with $_FILES and how to check for pictures and how to convert it to a JPEG without saving it to disk.

Comment: After `move_uploaded_file` your image path is `/tmp/classify-img` not `/tmp/classify-img/tmp/phpfapzyK`.

Comment: so what needs to be removed here for this to work that I am not seeing, I do not understand at this point and have been humbled down to ask so I do not lose another day doing this

Comment: `imagejpeg` accepts a `GdImage` object as the first argument not a path. And why are you saving it with he worst possible quality? There are numerous PHP tutorials on how to properly handle uploaded files and convert images. If you don't want to lose another day, then start reading tutorials and documentation.

Comment: I was able to fix it because of your two comments. Thank you. I updated the code above and hopefully this helps some people out in the future google searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a common way to handle temporary files is to create the file, open it, and then unlink/delete it without closing the handle. This gives you the ability to use disk while ensuring that the files are deleted/unlinked when the process ends. That is what is happening, why `move_uploaded_file()` exists at all, and why you *must* use it before any other operation on that file.

There is also the additional layer of "do you actually want this file to really exist?" because otherwise anyone can POST to any PHP script and have files created in the filesystem.

**TLDR:** You *must* use `move_uploaded_file()` before attempting to use the file.

Comment: this was part 1 of a a 3 part problem which I posted solved code above, thank you for helping.